# findMeetingTimes in MS Graph not returning all events for the period

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get events for a period of two months in the future, but the actual results are less than two months. The furthest event that I get from MS Graph is about 1.2 months in the future

Changing maxCandidates also doesn't help

Request body

```
{
"attendees": [{
    "type": "required",
    "emailAddress": {
        "address": "myuser@user.com"
    }
}],
"timeConstraint": {
    "activityDomain": "work",
    "timeSlots": [{
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2022-05-30 08:00:00",
            "timeZone": "Central European Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2022-07-29 22:59:59",
            "timeZone": "Central European Standard Time"
        }
    }]
},
"isOrganizerOptional": "true",
"meetingDuration": "PT60M",
"maxCandidates": 1000
}
```

Furthest response

```
        {
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2022-07-08T16:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Central European Standard Time"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2022-07-08T17:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Central European Standard Time"
            }
        }
```

So the furthest slot that I get from MS Graph is for 07-08 which isn't the furthest that I want to get from it (which is for 07-29)

Is findMeetingTimes limited to only 40 days? Can it be changed somehow in configuration? I can't find anything about it in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of days that Exchange tracks for FreeBusy time is 42 days it's not documented in FindMeetingTime but it is in GetSchedule and they both use the same underlying data https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule

> The time period to look up must be less than 42 days.

With Exchange OnPrem you could adjust the period by modifying the maximumQueryIntervalDays setting in the Web.Config but in Exchange Online this isn't user configurable.